# Replace a whole div code (with divs inside) with different code using php

Tags: php

I am getting a code of a page using ob_buffer and i try to replace all divs inside the page that contain the class locked-content.

While it's easy with jquery the problem is that with php is a bit harder. Let say for example i have this html code

```
<div class='class'> cool content </div>

<div class='class more-class life-is-hard locked-content'>

    <div class='cool-div'></div>
    <div class='anoter-cool-div'></div>

    some more code here

</div>

<div class='class'> cool content </div>
```

Now it seems like a complex task, I think i need to detect somehow how many divs are open after the div with the class 'locked-content' and then count how many closed div there are and when the wanted div was closed and then replace the code with new code while looping the code in case the div exists more than once.

Anyone has an idea on how to do something like this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via `DOMXPath`:

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$node = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "locked-content")]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    foreach ($node->childNodes as &$cNode) {
        if ($cNode instanceOf DOMElement && $cNode->tagName === 'div') {
            $cNode->replaceWith(/* Whatever */);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, i wasn't able to make it work it seems like there is error on the foreach and i can't use loadHtml with my string but i will try to play around with the code you sent and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Why can't you use loadHtml? Isn't it valid?

Comment: Hey, it seems like i got a warning when i used that but it it was valid.
I have to use libxml_use_internal_errors(true); to avoid the error.

I was able to create something that works now adjusting the code a bit and your query saved me a lot of time so i really do appreciate your help.